# No results found when i use postman

Tags: json, request, postman

I have a PHP code connected to mysql database. I want to send user login data from the postman tool and receive it in the php code and then return it to the result

The problem is that when sending data do not get the result

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$response = array();
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
include 'db/db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) ){
    $username = $input['username'];
    $password = $input['password'];
    $query    = "SELECT full_name , password_hash   , salt ,  email ,  id_con  , born , city  , country و card_id   ,cardstatus, cardvalue FROM member WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($fullName , $passwordHashDB ,$salt, $email  , $countryid , $born , $city , $country  ,$cardid  ,$cardstatus, $cardvalue);
        if($stmt->fetch()){
            //Validate the password
            if(password_verify(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),$passwordHashDB)){

                $response["status"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Login successful";
                $response["full_name"] = $fullName;
                $response["card_id"] = $cardid;
                $response["email"] = $email;
                $response["id_con"] = $countryid;
                $response["country"] = $country;
                $response["city"] = $city;
                $response["born"] = $born;
                $response["cardstatus"] = $cardstatus;
                $response["cardvalue"] = $cardvalue;


            }
            else{
                $response["status"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Invalid username and password combination";
            }
        }
        else{
            $response["status"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid username and password combination";
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
//Display the JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Please embed the image instead of posting its link.

Comment: If you send the same HTTP request in browser (or tools other than postman), can you get the expected result?

Comment: The photo has been inserted